# TypeError shown even-though,indices given are of integer value

Tags: python-3.x

Why is it showing

> TypeError: string indices must be integer

when I run the following code (it's not full code)

```
for i in range(length - k + 1):
     temp = int(s[i, i + k])   #Error occuring here
     sum_l = 0
```

Comment: What is `s`? A `numpy` matrix?

Comment: more context is needed here. We need to know what types the objects are

Comment: #!/bin/python3

import sys

def getMagicNumber(s, k, b, m):
    length=len(s)
    sum1=0
    for i in range(length-k+1):
        #print(type(s))
        temp=int(s[i,i+k])
        #print(temp)
        sum_l=0
        power=1
        while temp>0:
            sum_l=sum_l+(temp%10)*power
            power=power*b
            temp=temp/10
        sum_l=sum_l%m
        sum1=sum1+sum_l
    return sum1

s = input().strip()
k, b, m = input().strip().split(' ')
k, b, m = [int(k), int(b), int(m)]
result = getMagicNumber(s, k, b, m)
print(result)

Comment: s is of type string

Comment: You are trying to index `s` with a *tuple* - `(i, i+k)`.  I suspect you meant to use a slice there - `s[i: i+k]`